# Hide menu icon in toolbar for some fragments in navigation drawer

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I am creating a single activity app using android architecture components like navigation graph. I have a login flow (sign in, sign up, etc) fragments which should have a title bar but not a menu icon(hamburger icon).

```
// App bar configuration
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
    setOf(
        R.id.splashFragment,
        R.id.signInFragment,
        R.id.homeFragment
    ),
    main_activity_layout
)
```

Using the above code, I managed to change back arrow (back navigation) to the menu icon. But I want the menu icon only in `homeFragment`. Neither menu icon nor back navigation arrow should be there in `splashFragment` and `signInFragment`.

I want a title bar, so hiding the app bar completely is not a solution.

Comment: Does this https://github.com/umangburman/Navigation-Drawer-With-Navigation-Component help?

Comment: @Raghunandan No it is not what I want

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`OnDestinationChangedListener`](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_events):

```
 navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
            if (destination.id == R.id.homeFragment) {
                drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED)
            } else {
                drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)
            }
        }
```